# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/14: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android

i want to upload a ms word file or a PDF file or any other kind of text file..to the server.but when i chose the file from my mobile storage and tried to click on upload button it throws the exception `java.io. File Not Found Exception: /document/14: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

this is my code to choose the file from phone

```
 private void showFileChooser()
    {
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e(CONSTANTS.TAG, "showFileChooser: "+ex.toString() );
        }
    }
```

And this is the code for Activity Result

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 7:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    path = data.getData().getPath();

                    if(path!=null)
                        tvFilePath.setText(path);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

i expect to get the file on the exact path and convert that into base64 to upload on the server using asp.net web api but it throws the exception when choose the file from my phone storage `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/14: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Your code is incorrect. Cause you call `startActivityForResult(intent, 7);` but you show us method `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` at least, it has 3 arguments instead 2 in your `startActivityForResult`. I mean, code in your question

Comment: actually i have taken this code from some site and i m not able to understand the problem

Comment: What is `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` who calls that? because in your `showFileChooser()` you call `startActivityForResult(intent, 7);`

Comment: onActivityResult() executes when we call the method startActivityForResult();

Comment: How, I can't see that :) Could show full code about that or show site where you find that code?

Comment: yeah sure that's the site......https://www.mytrendin.com/android-pick-file-programatically/

Comment: Hmm, I see some changing in your code. Have you tried exactly as is in the example?

Comment: i didn't need the whole code ..i only took the desired part and applied that

Comment: hey Dred.there is one more thing i want to tell you ...before trying all this solutions i had some other code in my project that was pretty fine and really worked well and was exactly fulfilling my need but there was an issue with that code ..that worked well on my phone but didn't work on any other phone that's why i had to change that and look for some other solution...would you like to see that code?

Comment: i really don't know that how can i make that work on all the other phones too

Comment: Try to look [that](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/72). It is possible, that you have all privileges on your phone but none on others?

Comment: yes i have already added all the permissions in the manifest file

Comment: at least, try to add into a log the full path of the file which you try to open. To see, what file you phone tries to open. Or `/document/14` is a full?

Comment: it shows /document/14 as the full path

Comment: You WON'T get an absolute path to a file. The code you have written gives you an URI to a file. You need to write your own logic to process the FILE pointed by this. Follow the docs at: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider

Comment: Rahul Shukla ..i don't understand how to get the actual path from uri..can you help this?